# Intel NUC not finding my WiFi -

Tags: networking, drivers

Good afternoon, 
I am fairly Ubuntu basic. As in, I understand about as much as I can read - but every time I open up the Terminal, I am afraid I am going to break something.

Anyways - I've recently moved and I can no longer run an ethernet cable directly into my NUC. I have installed a WiFi card (Intel 7260) but I have never gotten it to work.

Here is the link to my Wireless info log: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KBkwpjvthg/

While I've been reading through fixes on this site, and others, I have yet to find something that makes sense enough to me, that will bring up a working WiFi. If you would need any further information, I am happy to provide it.

Cheers!

Comment: It looks like you have a MAC filter in the router.

Comment: I notice that there are *NO* scan results, not even at very low signal strength. When you installed the wireless card, are you quite certain that you connected both antenna wires? https://www.pcper.com/files/imagecache/article_max_width/review/2013-09-19/IMG_1430.JPG  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: ... wow. Sure DIDN'T DO THAT.

Comment: Well - now that that is done - everything seems to be working GREAT.

Thanks for your help - and another pair of eyes to see my STUPIDITY, 
Also, chili555 - You're EXTREMELY helpful on this site. It was mostly your suggestions I was following before I reaized the error of my ways - so way to be awesome.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. I'm glad it's working now! Have fun!

Comment: @chili555 That's not a comment!  That's an answer!  Please post an answer, ping me [at]Fabby and I'll come back and upvote!  **;-)**

Comment: Consider accepting the answer below as the correct one by putting the green check mark on its left margin. This helps others find answers that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that there are NO scan results, not even at very low signal strength. When you installed the wireless card, are you quite certain that you connected *both* antenna wires?

[image]

Please check. Be certain that both wires are connected and securely snapped in place. Restart the NUC and see if there are wireless networks available at the Network Manager icon.

Comment: @Fabby I wish they were all this easy!